# Remove fraction from an address in pandas data frame

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe in pandas which I would like to remove fractions from the column with addresses. I can't figure out the correct regress implementation to remove them.

The sample addresses look like:

```
580 1/4 Broadway Street

85 1/4 Grand Street
```

Two things, I'm not sure how to loop through the dataframe to remove the special characters.

And two what is the correct regex function and how do I regroup the flags?

I came up with

"^(.*)\d+/\d+\s(.*)" 
and
"\1\2" to group the flags together

Or is there just a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **`str.replace`**, you don't need matching groups at all.

```
df.address.str.replace(r'\d+\/\d+', '')

0    580  Broadway Street
1        85  Grand Street
Name: address, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was banging my head against the wall trying to figure that out. Works perfectly.

Comment: Actually one last question, replace(r'\d+\/\d+', '') leaves 2 spaces between the # and street name. How do I remove 1 space?

Comment: `df.address.str.replace(r'\d+\/\d+\s', '')`, although might be safer to use `df.address.str.replace(r'\d+\/\d+\s?', '')`